# I want to insert multiple rows in a table using sql server 2005

Tags: sql

I am wanting to insert rows into a four column table. I have inserted rows in the first two columns. However, when I try adding to the third and fourth column I receive the following error,

> "Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 String or binary data would be
>   truncated. The statement has been terminated"

I am using the following query:

```
USE DB
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Table (Column1, Column2, Column3,Column4)
VALUES ('data','data','data','data')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if one of your strings exceeds the length of the datafield.
For example, if you are inserting a string of length 50 into a varchar(20), you would recieve this error.

Comment: Thanks. I increased the column size and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving that error because your columns are not capable of storing a value that large.  You need to either shorten the length of your strings being inserted or increased the length on the column structure.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I increased the length on the column structure and that resolved the error.